# Data Transfer tool with integrity verification

Tags: ftp, file-transfer

Is there any data transfer tool other than *globus* that explicitly checks integrity of the local files after data transfer? I think *rsync* has this option but I can not make it work. I was wondering if there any other tools that does the same?

Comment: what was the problem with `rsync` ?

Comment: rsync only read the local file at sender end. I need something that do the same at both ends

Comment: rsync can check the md5 of files and report if not match, does it help?

Comment: Yeah, I know that rsync does that. But I am looking for something that does end to end integrity verification